# MVC and Asp.net hybrid Application starting point

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0

I have a MVC and Asp.net hybrid Application I have one controller but it doesn't have any home controller, I don't want to start application from mvc view I need to start from default.aspx

When I write "default.aspx" at the end of url it works fine. but it doesn't work when I write mysite.com/

Also I have a web service but it isn't working now. because of routing like : "mywebservice.asmx/mymethodname"

How I can set my global.asax ? what configuration I need for running in this combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create your MVC application in a sub folder of your web application and then move any Global.asax configuration to your WebForms app

You will just need to update your routing, if your MVC app was created in a folder called MVC it might look something like this:

```
           routes.MapRoute(
           "MVC default",                                              
           "MVC/default.aspx",                                         
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  
          );

        routes.MapRoute(
           "Services",
           "MVC/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );
```

Edit:

Actually you would need to map sure your views are mapped correctly too, you could do this by creating a quick custom view engine:

```
        public class CustomViewEngine : System.Web.Mvc.WebFormViewEngine
{
    public CustomViewEngine()
    {
        base.ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
          "~/MVC/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
          "~/MVC/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
          "~/MVC/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
          "~/MVC/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx"
        };

           base.PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] {
         "~/MVC/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
          "~/MVC/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
          "~/MVC/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
          "~/MVC/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx"
        };

           base.MasterLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
          "~/MVC/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
          "~/MVC/Views/Shared/{0}.master"
        };
    }

}
```

and then registering it in your global.asax:

```
        System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
```